MudBlazor theme colors change on page refresh
I'm building a Blazor WASM app with MudBlazor and I'm using custom themes for light and dark mode.
The theme provider is in the MainLayout.razor file:
<MudThemeProvider Theme="@_theme" IsDarkMode="_isDarkMode" />

The _isDarkMode field is first initialized to null:
private MudTheme? _theme = null;

But them gets an instance in OnInitialized():
protected async override void OnInitialized()
{
    base.OnInitialized();
    _theme = new()
        {
            PaletteLight = _lightPalette,
            PaletteDark = _darkPalette,
            LayoutProperties = new LayoutProperties()
        };
}

The themes are defined lower in the same file:
private readonly PaletteLight _lightPalette = new()
    {
        Black = "#110e2d",
        AppbarText = "#424242",
        AppbarBackground = "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)",
        DrawerBackground = "#ffffff",
        GrayLight = "#e8e8e8",
        GrayLighter = "#f9f9f9",
    };

private readonly PaletteDark _darkPalette = new()
    {
        Primary = "#7e6fff",
        Surface = "#1e1e2d",
        Background = "#1a1a27",
        BackgroundGray = "#151521",
        AppbarText = "#92929f",
        AppbarBackground = "rgba(26,26,39,0.8)",
        DrawerBackground = "#1a1a27",
        ActionDefault = "#74718e",
        ActionDisabled = "#9999994d",
        ActionDisabledBackground = "#605f6d4d",
        TextPrimary = "#b2b0bf",
        TextSecondary = "#92929f",
        TextDisabled = "#ffffff33",
        DrawerIcon = "#92929f",
        DrawerText = "#92929f",
        GrayLight = "#2a2833",
        GrayLighter = "#1e1e2d",
        Info = "#4a86ff",
        Success = "#3dcb6c",
        Warning = "#ffb545",
        Error = "#ff3f5f",
        LinesDefault = "#33323e",
        TableLines = "#33323e",
        Divider = "#292838",
        OverlayLight = "#1e1e2d80",
    };

The problem is, when I refresh any page, the colors change for some reason. The mode (dark/light) stays the same but the colors are a bit brighter in dark mode. Like if they got reset to some default values.
The colors I want:

The colors I get after a refresh in the browser:

If I now open the hamburger menu or switch the mode to light and then back to dark the colors get corrected.
What am I doing wrong that the colors are not correct right after the refresh?

Apparently, it was enough to move around these two calls in OnInitialized().
It seems that base.OnInitialized() takes the default theme colors and applies them and then calls StateHasChanged() to redraw the GUI and I apply my custom colors after that.
I could call StateHasChanged() again in my code but the result is that I can see the default colors for a split second before my colors are applied. Moving the custom color setting before base.OnInitialized() solved the issue as now my custom colors are set up before anything else.
MainLayout.razor:
protected async override void OnInitialized()
{
    _theme = new()
        {
            PaletteLight = _lightPalette,
            PaletteDark = _darkPalette,
            LayoutProperties = new LayoutProperties()
        };

    base.OnInitialized();
}


This sounds like a strange solution, because ComponentBase.OnInitialized() contains no code. Perhaps there's some magic going on when it's compiled. In that case I hope someone can enlighten me.

@PawBaltzersen, there might be some code in the Blazor framework which uses Reflection to figure out when OnInitialized() is called and executes some extra code after that. But I don't know for sure.

After analyzing the code in the template, I found that _isDarkMode is always true every time the page is refreshed. This is the root cause.
We can store the value of _isDarkMode in localStorage or other places, and load it when refreshing the page to load the selected theme.
The problem found in the test is that StateHasChanged(); will cause the page to load and the theme will change after a while, because the pre-loaded theme is still DarkMode.
Here is the sample for you.
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<MudThemeProvider Theme="@_theme" IsDarkMode="_isDarkMode" />
<MudPopoverProvider />
<MudDialogProvider />
<MudSnackbarProvider />
<MudLayout>
    <MudAppBar Elevation="1">
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" OnClick="@((e) => DrawerToggle())" />
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h5" Class="ml-3">Application</MudText>
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudIconButton Icon="@(DarkLightModeButtonIcon)" Color="Color.Inherit" OnClick="@DarkModeToggle" />
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.MoreVert" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.End" />
    </MudAppBar>
    <MudDrawer @bind-Open="_drawerOpen" ClipMode="DrawerClipMode.Always" Elevation="2">
        <NavMenu />
    </MudDrawer>
    <MudMainContent Class="mt-16 pa-4">
        @Body
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>

<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>

@code {
    private bool _drawerOpen = true;
    private bool _isDarkMode = true;
    private MudTheme? _theme = null;
    private bool _initialized = false;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var savedDarkMode = await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("localStorage.getItem", "isDarkMode");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(savedDarkMode))
            {
                _isDarkMode = bool.Parse(savedDarkMode);
                StateHasChanged();
            }

            _theme = new MudTheme
            {
                PaletteLight = _lightPalette,
                PaletteDark = _darkPalette,
                LayoutProperties = new LayoutProperties()
            };

            _initialized = true;
            StateHasChanged(); 
        }
    }

    private void DrawerToggle()
    {
        _drawerOpen = !_drawerOpen;
    }

    private async Task DarkModeToggle()
    {
        _isDarkMode = !_isDarkMode;
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("localStorage.setItem", "isDarkMode", _isDarkMode.ToString().ToLower());
    }

    private readonly PaletteLight _lightPalette = new()
    {
        Black = "#110e2d",
        AppbarText = "#424242",
        AppbarBackground = "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)",
        DrawerBackground = "#ffffff",
        GrayLight = "#e8e8e8",
        GrayLighter = "#f9f9f9",
    };

    private readonly PaletteDark _darkPalette = new()
    {
        Primary = "#7e6fff",
        Surface = "#1e1e2d",
        Background = "#1a1a27",
        BackgroundGray = "#151521",
        AppbarText = "#92929f",
        AppbarBackground = "rgba(26,26,39,0.8)",
        DrawerBackground = "#1a1a27",
        ActionDefault = "#74718e",
        ActionDisabled = "#9999994d",
        ActionDisabledBackground = "#605f6d4d",
        TextPrimary = "#b2b0bf",
        TextSecondary = "#92929f",
        TextDisabled = "#ffffff33",
        DrawerIcon = "#92929f",
        DrawerText = "#92929f",
        GrayLight = "#2a2833",
        GrayLighter = "#1e1e2d",
        Info = "#4a86ff",
        Success = "#3dcb6c",
        Warning = "#ffb545",
        Error = "#ff3f5f",
        LinesDefault = "#33323e",
        TableLines = "#33323e",
        Divider = "#292838",
        OverlayLight = "#1e1e2d80",
    };

    public string DarkLightModeButtonIcon => _isDarkMode switch
    {
        true => Icons.Material.Rounded.AutoMode,
        false => Icons.Material.Outlined.DarkMode,
    };
}


MudBlazor uses the system settings by default. You can disable this with <MudThemeProvider ObserveSystemThemeChange="false"/>

@Taco Thanks, let me check it and if it works, will update my answer. For this issue, I just tell op why the theme-colors-change on page fresh.

@Taco After testing, ObserveSystemThemeChange does not solve the problem well. I think MudBlazor can provide a more elegant way to switch/save themes. Currently, private bool _isDarkMode = true; may have some problems. Maybe I haven't found the right article tutorial yet.
